# Scrape Data in C# from images

Tags: c#

Scrape Data in C# from images

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot the actual question part.

Comment: i want all the text from the images "Scrape Data in C# from images"

Comment: It's called OCR. Optical Character Recognition.

Comment: look at http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to buy an OCR library. There seem to a variety of them out there.

http://www.componentsource.com/features/scanning-ocr/net-class/index.html